# assign column values to variable out of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

I read an excel sheet into a data frame. Is there a possibility to loop over the columns and assign a list with the values of each column to a variable that has the column name as a variable name?
So as a simple example I have the data frame

```
val = [[1,396,29],[2,397,29],[3,395,29],[4,393,29],[5,390,29],[6,398,29]]
df=pd.DataFrame(val,columns=['Hours','T1T_in','T1p_in'])
df
```

```
Hours   T1T_in  T1p_in
0   1   396 29
1   2   397 29
2   3   395 29
3   4   393 29
4   5   390 29
5   6   398 29
```

so I would like to have a loop creating lists with column Name as variable?

```
Hours = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
T1T_in = [396,397,395,393,390,398]
T1p_in = [29,29,29,29,29,29,29]
```

I find a solution for getting the names out but can not assign the values. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to get column elements as list is to use `pandas.Series.tolist()` :

```
Hours = df.Hours.to_list()
T1T_in = df.T1p_in.to_list()
T1p_in = df.T1p_in.to_list()
```

you can also use a for loop(as you mantion that you want) to get the columns and the rows if you want:

```
data = {}
for column_name, rows in df.iteritems():
    data[column_name] = rows.to_list()

print(data)
```

**output:**

```
{'Hours': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 'T1T_in': [396, 397, 395, 393, 390, 398],
 'T1p_in': [29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29]}
```

the above result can also be achieved with :

```
df.to_dict('list')
```

as @anky_91 was saying

Answer (score 0):

It works so far. But I have one question. I still do not understand how I can access to the values for each variable now. In the following I want to work with these lists and calculate some items. A simplified example you can see below.
Thank you once again.

```
new=[]
for i in range(len(hours)):
    new.append(T1T_in[i]+T1p_in[I])
```

Thank you once again for your help

Comment: if my post was helpful you can upvote or accept, for a new question, I will suggest posting a new question, thx!